# Memory issue on Android 4.0

Tags: android, memory, layout

I had worked on an Android application with 2.2 at the beginning. It works properly on a cell phone or tablet with 2.2 or 3.2.

But now I have tried on a cell phone with 4.0.3. There are two issues for which I can't figure out the solution yet.

1. Out of memory issue : It says out of memory and then crash. I haven't faced it on 2.2. 
   In fact, I just set those images in the layout xml. I am not sure what is the differences in 2.2 and 4.0.
2. Layout problem. The layout is wrong. I use the xml file to set the image position and size.
   I have no idea why it doesn't work, especially the font size,the numbers in the values part.
   They are totally different from what i see at android 2.2

Comment: Here is more details about my issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449783/android-app-2-2-port-to-4-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem one :

Its not the `2.2 - 4.0` issue,but the memory difference in the mobile  handsets. With the given information,this is all I can say :) Also have a look at : [Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Problem two :

This is why you recommended to use a `Layout` and NEVER do Absolute positioning (Which I strongly suspect you did) !

Have a look at :

1. [XML Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)
2. [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have tried on the same device with 2.3 and 4.0. why there is no memory issue on 2.3 but it happens on 4.0 ? So I wonder if there is any changes on the 4.0?

Comment: @AlanLee I'm not sure why, let someone else answer :)

Answer (score 0):

1) You should have to monitor the memory and number of object instance in your app in both 2.2 and 4.0 with the help of **ddms** or any other eclipse tool. And about the memory allocation for Android app, Android allocate every app **initially** with some heap memory (eg. say 4MB) for running app and it also have the **max memory allocation** limit (eg. say 16 MB) for every app. If application requires more memory which initially allocated it extends the allocation at runtime(i.e. from 4MB to 6MB or 8MB and more depending on requirement) upto max memory(eg. i.e. 16MB). And if App require more memory than Max Memory then an **OutOfMemoryError** occur. you can monitor the max memory and free memory with the help of [Runtime](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html) class and [Debug](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html) class.

2) And for layouting issue never use pixel value always use Dp values and never use Absolute layout.

Use nine patch Images for different resolution devices.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I am trying to use ddms. I have created a new activity, it has already 16MB when there is only hello world on Galaxy Note with 4.0.3. I am stilling looking at the issue.

For my apps,if it runs on 2.3 Galaxy S.it just takes allocated 2.79MB. But on Note with 4.0.3,it is 54MB at the beginning. It is same code and same layout and image. I have looked into the hprof,it mainly come from the byte[] and android.graphic.Bitmap.><

i am going to try .but i also find a strange thing in if i get the height of the image,it gives me the double of the original height.

Comment: For the layout,all of them are either use dp,wrap_content or fill_parent and all relative layout

Comment: I have figured out the reason but i am not 100% sure. It is because i use drawable-large-xhdpi for note version. It can be used in 2.X but in ICS 4.0.it is unable to enter this folder.then it scales up the image of the default which then cause the memory issue and layout problem too. btw,i still need to test more to sure this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue.
I am suspecting it has something to do with hardware acceleration. From 3.x on (not sure exactly when it was) hardware acceleration is turned on by default. Which seems to be causing a lot of issues when dealing with graphics (for example you can't use clip with hardware acceleration on).

Sorry its not a full answer but thought it might help you search for answers.

---

I just actually figured out what the problem was for my app and am hoping you are having the same issue.

try relocating your resources into corresponding drawable folders (drawable-mdpi, hdpi so on). apparently the drawable folder defaults to drawable-mdpi and devices with higher dpi will expand the resource and load it in, causing the resource image to be bigger than what you expect.
In my case I only had 1 size for all, so i put my big images like backgrounds into drawable-nodpi and i stopped getting OOM errors. hope this helps!