# Android app 2.2 port to 4.0

Tags: android, image, memory, layout

I have built an application based on 2.2.It works properly and does well. However, when i put the application on the 4.0(with resolution 1280x800 Samsung Galaxy Note). It crashes and says it runs out of memory randomly and with wrong layout which doesn;t fix the size

Here is my situation, 
I have totally about 100 images(most of them are .png and .jpg) within 5 activities (normally 1 background image,20 button background images with focus and normal one) and about 2MB in file size.

I set the image and layout in the xml like relative layout background or button background or just imageview.

I wonder why it runs out of memory as in the drawable folder size is just 2MB and why it runs out of memory and why does it work on 2.2 but fail on 4.0.

I hope if anyone can help me.

The first concern is the layout. For example, the button size is relatively large than the one in 2.2. So I am afraid of its scaling may affect the memory issue. In my button xml,i set it to be wrap_content for both width and height.I have no idea why it will be large than i expected. My thought is there are some differences on the layout xml in 4.0, it will make the layout strange or doing some scale then make the memory strange. In fact, all the images are just 2MB,is it possible to run out of memory?

The second concern is the memory.May be the memory handling is different from previous version.So do i need to make some adjustment in order to make it works on 4.0? Neglect the layout problem,may be i can further calibrate the position and size.But now i am unable to display the layout so I guess there is something to do on 4.0?

Finally,is it possible to find out how much memory used for each imageView or button? with this tools,may be can further investigate the problem.

If you are free,please help me.

Comment: did you run it to your emulator? or a any mobile devices?

Comment: this is a main drawback in android , images support mainly below 1mb safely. But you can resize the image By BitmapFactory

Comment: You can check the garbage and heap collection in DDMS

Comment: Thanks.I have resolved this problem. The reason is ICS unable to determine the right drawable folder with 2 parameter so I have changed to one parameter and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your images in corresponding drawable folders such as drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi and so on.

if you only have one version try putting them in drawable-nodpi. You might need to select which ones to put in nodpi depending on how your layout is setup.

when a xhdpi or hdpi device loads drawables from drawable or drawable-mdpi, the system automatically enlarged the resource to match the dpi. from mdpi to xhdpi the drawable will be resized to 2x the size and 1.5x for mdpi to hdpi.

hope this helps :)